# How to Convert Python code to exe for macOS?

Tags: python, macos, exe

I've developed an application in Python with PyCharm on Windows OS and I want to make a `.exe` file for macOS. How can I do this?

I don't have a macOS, can I do it?

Comment: [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) means something very specific and it's not a brand of computer.

Comment: PyCharm does not generate executables ! Can't you run the .py file on the Mac ?

Comment: I suggest first you look for a package that creates a Python executable. There are many of them. Then try it using a virtual machine or inside a docker container - simply create a docker container that acts like your choice of operating system.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `PyInstaller` tool to create executables for both Windows and mac.
However, you need a mac for the mac executable version

Comment: But you must run PyInstsller on a Mac to create a Mac executable. Same for Linux, you need a Linux system to create a Linux executable.

Comment: Could you tel me more